# Issue with tab view data persistency in Openui5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sapui5

My application has tabs. So in a single session I open multiple tabs and each tab renders some data by doing ajax calls from db. But my problem is when I switch tabs my data gets refreshed each time I switch a tab. How can I freeze the data by not refreshing each time I switch the tab until I close it. I guess it is due to it is destroying the tab view everytime but is there a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's because you would be destroying the tab view.

Workaround:

1. Set your data to some app level variable(global to only app)
2. If you have CRUD operations, have a flag to when to delete this data to null.